# IE 9 doesn't like custom html tags

Tags: html, internet-explorer, internet-explorer-9

I have sample html below. It has custom html tag which I replace with some value before sending it to browser. If I don't have any value for those tags, I do nothing. It works all fine in IE7/8/10 / FF and chrome. 
**But not in IE9**

Some `<td>` increases or decreases its width automatically. I see that when I change the Document Mode=IE9 Standards via Web Developer Tools.

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.0 Transitional//EN">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <title></title>

    <style>
        .id {width:150px;}
        .text{width:450px;}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <table id="test">
        <tr><td class="id">11</td><td class="text">One</td></tr>
         <tr><td class="id">22</td><td class="text">Two</td></tr>
         <tr><td>33</td><td class="text">Three</td ></tr>
        <TEST/>
        <HELLOWORLD/>
        <tr><td>44</td><td class="text">Four</td></tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

**Current Fix:**
If I don't have any value, I replace it with empty string on server side before sending to client.

**Question:** Any idea why this happens only in IE9 or have any other better solution than what I currently have.

Note: That is just the small version of my actual production code but it replicates the issue. In here it is reducing the width but in my production code, it is increasing the width of some `<td>`. JSFiddle [here](http://jsfiddle.net/3VB2w/).

Comment: Not that this is a good answer, but there are a lot of compatibility issues between browsers, css, etc. using custom elements, at least that was my experience. You'd be better off using `<div>`s with classes/ids instead, IMO.

Comment: “IE 9 doesn't like custom html tags” is not a problem description, and neither is “doesn’t work”. And of course you shouldn’t leave made-up tags in HTML code when they cannot possibly serve a useful purpose.

Comment: IEs are bad when fixing invalid HTML. Custom tags are not valid tags within [`table`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/table#Usage_context). If you'll retrieve the inner HTML of the page, you'd probably see, that IE has set your custom tags outside of the table.

Comment: Thank you guys. I will stick to my solution, to remove the unwanted placeholders tags before sending them to client.

Answer (score 1):

I know it's a bit late ... but I'm looking into custom tags right now and I'd like to add my 2 cents.

Custom tags are required to contain a hyphen ( '-' ) in their name. Valid names would be `<hello-world />` or `<menu-box></menu-box>`.

See http://w3c.github.io/webcomponents/spec/custom/ for the spec.

Comment: There's a lot more to web components than just custom tags. And the spec is still being worked on; it's subject to change, plus it isn't supported in all browsers yet -- it's still marked as "under consideration" for IE/Edge, and it is available in Firefox but only behind an 'experimental features' flag. But the real story is that the "Web Components" spec isn't intended just for arbitrary custom elements; it's intended for custom-written control widgets made up of custom elements. Use of custom tags on their own is still not encouraged.

Answer (score 0):

The short answer is: don't use custom tags; they're just not a good idea and you will have cross-browser issues if you use them. (there are some formal specs to allow you to use them, but they'll only work in the very latest browser versions)

IE8 and earlier don't support custom tags at all. You report that IE7/8 are working, so I guess they will be ignoring your custom elements entirely.

IE9 knows about HTML5 and thus it recognises that tags it doesn't know about might be valid, so it does allow them, but still within the rules of HTML.

And that's what's tripping you up: The rules of HTML state that the only elements allowed as a child of `<table>` are `<tbody>`, `<thead>`, `<tfoot>` and `<tr>`. Anything else is illegal. Therefore your elements are being seen as invalid HTML, and are thus causing your rendering issues.

The difference between IE9 and IE10 is probably in how well they handle the invalid HTML.

The solution is what you're already doing -- don't have those elements in your HTML. Invalid HTML is always going to give you rendering problems, and there's really no good reason to have invalid HTML.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case this is helpful for anyone. IE9's custom/arbitrary tags look like this:

```
<%tag>
```

I predominantly use this while testing for XSS:

```
<%xss onmouseover=alert()>click here!
```

Hovering the text "click here" gives a popup. Maybe this info is helpful for developers somehow.